# Chrome extension with angular: cannot init fields with chrome API

Tags: angular, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to write a chrome extension with Angular. I wrote the below component for the popup

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: ` Current tab: {{ currentTab || '(empty)' }} `,
  styles: []
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  currentTab: string;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getCurrentTabTitle().subscribe(title => this.currentTab = title);
  }

  getCurrentTabTitle() {
    return new Observable<string>(subscriber => {
      chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true }, tabs => {
        subscriber.next(tabs[0].title);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

The callback in `tabs.query()` is indeed called but the content remains `"Current tab: (empty)"`.
Why is it so?

Comment: I tried to paste your code in stackblitz to study your problem. The CLI said it could not find the module import {chrome} from '@types/chrome'; Are you using this module or another?

Comment: You need @types/chrome

Comment: Please read https://www.npmjs.com/package/child_process